# How to format JSON for Jquery UI autocomplete?

Tags: javascript, json, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I am trying to create an autocomplete with Jquery UI, i was having problem before of not knowing why it isnt working. And now i have filtered the problem down and got it to a single focused area.

Situation

1.) Auto complete works if the data is local.

2.) Auto complete does not work because the JSON data does not come in the exact same format.

3.) Not sure how to make the JSON data echo in the same format as the local data.

Javascript that works locally:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(function() {
  $( "#zip" ).autocomplete({
  source: [ {label:"705",value:"AIBONITO",state:"PR"},{label:"610",value:"ANASCO",state:"PR"},{label:"611",value:"ANGELES",state:"PR"},{label:"612",value:"ARECIBO",state:"PR"},{label:"601",value:"ADJUNTAS",state:"PR"}],
    minLength: 1,
    select: function( event, ui ) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $('#zip').val(ui.item.label);
            this.value = ui.item.label;
            $('#city').val(ui.item.value);
        $('#state').val(ui.item.state);
    }
  });
});

    </script>
```

Data needs to be in this format:

```
[ {label:"705",value:"AIBONITO",state:"PR"},{label:"610",value:"ANASCO",state:"PR"},{label:"611",value:"ANGELES",state:"PR"},{label:"612",value:"ARECIBO",state:"PR"},{label:"601",value:"ADJUNTAS",state:"PR"}]
```

Javascript remote:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(function() {
  $( "#zip" ).autocomplete({
  source: 'autozip.php',
    minLength: 1,
    select: function( event, ui ) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $('#zip').val(ui.item.label);
            this.value = ui.item.label;
            $('#city').val(ui.item.value);
        $('#state').val(ui.item.state);
    }
  });
});

    </script>
```

And the JSON will come in with double quotation like this, and it won't work:

```
 [ {"label":"705","value":"AIBONITO","state":"PR"},{"label":"610","value":"ANASCO",state:"PR"},{"label":"7885","value":"WHARTON","state":"NJ"},{"label":"7981","value":"WHIPPANY","state":"NJ"},]
```

Trying to figure out how to remove the double quotation around the label, value and state. 
THanks for your time!

Comment: The double quote does not affect the result. Your issue should be caused by other things.

Comment: But it stops working when the JSON is coming in, and it echos with no problem in a new php. the only difference between the local and the remote results are the double quotation though.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(function() {
    $( "#zip" ).autocomplete({
        source: function (req, res) {
            $.get('autozip.php?q=' + req.term).then(function (data) {
                res(data);
            });
        },
        minLength: 1,
        select: function( event, ui ) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $('#zip').val(ui.item.label);
            this.value = ui.item.label;
            $('#city').val(ui.item.value);
            $('#state').val(ui.item.state);
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: OK. Please add `console.log(data)` before `res(data)` to check the output.

Comment: Hi, just tried it, the JSON is displayed within the log, but it doesnt create the auto complete. And i am wondering if there is a way to load the data straight away when the page is loaded(but not load the data when the letter is typed in the input box)? Because there are a lot of data and it takes like 1-2 seconds to load all of them.

Comment: actually, your backend page should filter the request letter to generate the result dynamically, then **only return the suggested 10 records**. I have updated the answer.